# RequireJS Questions for Rails 3/Backbone App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, asset-pipeline, requirejs

I have a semi-large (~25 views) Backbone app (on top of Rails 3.2), which I'm considering using RequireJS for, and I have a few questions.

If all of my JS is already compiled into one file (via Rails' asset pipeline), what are the advantages of using RequireJS?  More specifically, are there any performance benefits?

If I'm loading files asynchronously, is there a way to require a module for a piece of code, but still execute that piece of code?

E.G. I'd like to render a view regardless of whether the [JS uploader files](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) have loaded.  If the JS has not been loaded, I could add 'disabled' to the buttons.  When the JS does arrive, the template could be re-rendered, but this time exclude the 'disabled' attributes and attach the uploader JS to the button.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I wouldn't use RequireJS and rails at the same time, they are both solving the same problem (multiple files in dev, single file in production) and will interfere with each other.

Comment: @OlliM So not true. At my company we are successfully using exactly this tech-stack – Rails, the Requirejs-gem and Backbone. It helped reducing the initial page-load and load in modules later on when needed.